# Understanding Google Sheet Add on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-marketplace, google-cloud-platform

I am creating a Google sheet add on, and it required me to create a project at google cloud platform.

I want to offer this add on for free to the community and have a question around it.

Now when i submit this in google sheet add on gallery, and people start using my extension, will I need to pay any bill for this google cloud platform project OR when they install it they will be using their google cloud platform resources?

thank you for your help.

Comment: Any advanced services that you enabled that are used by your add-on, run against the account that installed the add-on.  Why did you need to create a Google Cloud project?

Comment: Google cloud project is automatically created with a script.

Answer (score 0):

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/#wzxhzdk12wzxhzdk13charge_users_to_install

> Things you can't do > Charge users to install
>
> We don't yet provide a way to charge users for add-ons, and add-ons
>   can't include ads. However, you can roll your own payment system or
>   call into an existing billing database.

Regarding i you need to pay any bill, from https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/

> Free Items
>
> Several components of Google Cloud Platform, including Cloud
>   Deployment Manager, Cloud SDK, Cloud Resource Manager API, and this
>   Cloud Calculator are all provided free of charge.

For further details [Contact Sales](https://cloud.google.com/contact/)

Comment: thank you, my question is not about the costing of google cloud platform, but rather about how google sheet add on works when its installed by a user, does it consume my google cloud platform project resources when user runs the add on OR mine.

Comment: Question is not about whether I can charge the user or not as I plan to offer the extension for free.

But when these users run the extension (let say 10000 users run it), will the google cloud platform bill come to me OR they'll use the google cloud resources directly by only running my scripts.

Comment: @GelaRam It depends on what services your add-on use. If it only use Google Apps Script services, they are free but with limitations set by usage quotas.

Comment: my add on will use Gmail API and Google Admin Directory.

Comment: @GelaRam They are free services.